# Loading windows through grub

Tags: boot, grub2

I just want to know how to boot windows through the grub. I formated my hard disk even though when i tried to boot my system its starting from the Grub boot loader, how can i avoid this. I tried many ways mentioned in the internet but none of them works for me. Since there is no OS in my hard disk it is not even opening the system.

Comment: How exactly did you format your hard disk(s)? Boot loaders like Grub reside outside of any partitions. If you install any operating system it'll (offer to) overwrite pre-existing boot loaders. It's unclear to me how you intend to boot Windows, if at the same time you say “there is no OS in my hard disk”.

Answer (score 0):

If you really

> formated my hard disk ... Since there is no OS in my hard disk

then you might have erased windows... and it's not there to load anymore. May have to try data recovery to possibly recover the deleted partitions, or just the files, or just some unnamed files & data with a tool like `testdisk` or `photorec`, or if not worth it re-install windows. But make sure there's really no windows left on the HD first, browse around (mounted read-only if you have any future recovery in mind) and check.